# Workflow to copy document from list to list in a different site collection by using GUID?

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, guid, copy-item

I am trying to copy a single document from one document library to a document library in another site collection.

Here is an existing workflow that uses a GUID as a destination.  The GUID shown here is another document library.

[image: existing workflow copying a doc from source doc library to a GUID destination]

Yet when try to replicate this I am unable to select a GUID as a destination and instead am limited to document libraries within the same site collection.

Here's what I see:
[image: new workflow - unable to select a GUID, can only see another doc library as a destination]

Suggestions please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the **GUID** I saw in my original workflow refers to a **document library that has been deleted**.  It seems Sharepoint Designer display the GUID of the deleted document library instead of the name once the document library itself has been deleted.

I've found that it is **not possible to copy a document between site collections**.  Instead I will need a human to intervene!  I will handle this by sending a notification email to an administrator so that when the document (a template) is modified in one location, the administrator receives an email asking them to copy the modified file to the other location.

(BTW - in my opinion it is not best practise to save the same file in two locations anyway, but the reality is the folks want it done this way....)